# how to build a set of accessors that retrieve declared datas

Tags: java

```
public class student {

    public static void main(String[] args) {}

    private String name; 
    private String Idnumber;
    private String DOB;
    private String Gender;
    private String Address;
    private String schoolname;
    private int Grade ;
    private double GPA;

    public student() {
        name = "ABC";
        Idnumber = "12345678";
        DOB = "1-1-1999";
        Gender = "male";
        Address = "123 Main Street";
        schoolname = "ABC";
        Grade = 99; 
        GPA = 4.0;
    }
}
```

This is a default constructor that I had to built now I'm trying to build the accessors.
Sorry for any mistakes in the code, I'm a beginner.

Comment: **JAVA != JAVASCRIPT**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to ***research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself*** before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Accessors are a simple concept: each variable that is declared in your class (e.g. `name`, `Idnumber`, etc.) should be a `private` variable that requires a *getter* and *setter* method. For example:

```
public class Student
{
    //Declare private variables here.
    private String name;

    //Constructor.
    public Student()
    {
        name = "ABC";
    }

    //Method to access the "name" variable.
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    //Method to set a new value to the "name" variable.
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

In a similar way you would create a *getter* and *setter* for all other variables as well. You would need to ensure the correct variable types are used each time (e.g. `private int Grade;` will have a `public int getGrade() {...}` and also a `public void setGrade(int grade) {...}`.

You may also want to ensure the names of all classes start with a capital letter (e.g. `Student`) and the names of all variables utilize camel-case format so they begin with a lowercase letter (e.g. `gender`, `address`, etc.) as it is common practice to do so.